# How to disable logs for an angular app with MSAL

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I'm using Microsoft Authentication Library **msal** in an angular application. When I run the production version of the application, I see the following logs in the console. How can disable the logging?

[image]

Comment: Do you have ` enableTracing` turn on? this is the second parameter to RouterModule.forRoot

Comment: It is set as ```enableTracing: environment.production``` which means it is set for only production.

Comment: You should disable tracing in production, and even development. Only enable it when you need it (i.e. debugging routing issues)

Comment: If you can post your comment as an answer, I can select it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable tracing in production and development. Only enable tracing when needed.

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      { enableTracing: false } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
]
```